# dropdownlistfor not selecting what's supposed to be selected upon page load

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this helper. Now, this isn't mine. This is for displaying and populating the dropdown.

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<T, TTextProperty, TValueProperty>(this IEnumerable<T> instance, Func<T, TTextProperty> text, Func<T, TValueProperty> value, Func<T, bool> selectedItem = null)
        {
            return instance.Select(t => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = Convert.ToString(text(t)),
                Value = Convert.ToString(value(t)),
                Selected = selectedItem != null && selectedItem(t)
            });
        }
```

Then I have these classes:

```
public class FooVm {
  public FooVm() {
    Bars = new HashSet<BarVm>();
  }

  public int FooId { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<BarVm> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class BarVm {
  public int BarId { get; set; }
  public int BarName { get; set; }
}
```

Then having this Linq Query:

```
var fooBar = _db.Foo
                .WithId(fooId)
                .Select(f => new FooVm {
                  FooId = f.Id,
                  Bars = f.Bars.Select(b => new BarVm {
                    BarId = b.Id,
                    BarName = b.Name
                  })
                })
                .ToList();

ViewBag.Bars = _db.Bars
                  .ToSelectList(s => s.Name, s => s.Id);
```

Then when I try to render these result for editing/updating.

```
@model ViewModels.Foo.FooVm

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.FooId)
@foreach(var item in Model.Bars) {
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => item.BarId, ViewBag.Bars as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Select bar")
}
```

The dropdown is rendering fine but it isn't selecting of what's supposed to be selected upon page load.

What am I missing? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is actual point of this helper (as opposed to using one of the `SelectList` constructors - e.g. `new SelectList(_db.Bars, "BarId ", "BarName")`? And you `foreach` loop does not make sense - your generating duplicate `id` attributes (invalid html) and duplicate `name` attributes which don't bind to anything related you your model.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you so much. didn't know i could do something like that. got my markup corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your helper method takes up to 3 parameter but you are only supplying two. The third parameter allows you to set the selected Item by default this will be 'null'. See below for example.

```
ViewBag.Bars = Model.Bars.ToSelectList(s => s.BarName, s => s.BarId, s => s.BarId == 1);
```

**EDIT**

Try this, but since I don't understand your premise or what you are really trying to achieve this is just something to guide you.

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownListFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression,
                                               IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, string selectedValue, string optionLabel, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        Func<TModel, TValue> method = expression.Compile();
        string value = method(helper.ViewData.Model) as string;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && selectList != null)
        {
            var selectListList = selectList.ToList();
            var selectedItem = selectListList.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Selected);
            if (selectedItem == null)
            {
                var itemToSelect = selectListList.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Value == selectedValue);
                if (itemToSelect != null)
                {
                    itemToSelect.Selected = true;
                }
            }
            return helper.DropDownListFor(expression, selectListList, optionLabel, htmlAttributes);
        }

        return helper.DropDownListFor(expression, selectList, optionLabel, htmlAttributes);
    }
```

Use like this.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => item, ViewBag.Bars as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, item.BarId.ToString(), "Select bar", new object())
```

Test this thoroughly as this is just a quick prototype to show you how you can create the helper on your own.

The selected value can be overridden if you use the first answer as the `Selected` property of the `SelectListItem` will be `true`.

Comment: I thought you can set the selected value in razor markup `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => item.BarId, ViewBag.Bars as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Select bar")` Whatever is the value in the first parameter, it will set the selected value for you. I can't do something like you gave because it will only set the same value to all rendered dropdown.

Comment: The helper is simply providing you with a `SelectList` and setting the selected item in the list for you. If you want to be able to set the value directly in the `@Html.DropDownListFor` then you will need a helper that directly does that.

Comment: In your above code the `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => item.BarId, ViewBag.Bars as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Select bar")` `item.BarId` is actually doing nothing. [You can simply pass `Item` as it uses this parameter to determine what `object` the list is bound to.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703561%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Think you can provide sample solutions? It would be a great reference in the future and for others as well.